# assembly write to file x86

Tags: assembly, x86

The following code is ment to write foobar in a textfile. named tests.txt located in H. However it does no suchs thing it doesn't give me an error either it just leaves the file in the same state I found it. While decoding it seems %eax is 0 after calling _fopen which looks to me lik

```
blablaaa: .asciz "foobar /n"
filewritemode: .asciz "a"
filelocation: .asciz "/h/tests.txt"


_main:  

push $filewritemode
push $filelocation
call _fopen


push $blabla
push %eax 
call _fprintf
addl $16,%esp
push $0
call _exit # exit the program
```

I use gcc to compile this thing in case it matters and have been able to successfully call printf's before. 
When experimenting with playing sounds I found out that changing the location for the sound into just test.wav worked however this didn't work here could there be something to this? By the way Yes I have tried /H/test.txt H:/test.txt test.txt am I missing something? 
Or could this maybe be a permission issue?

Comment: Yes, it indicates an error if `%eax` is zero after the `_fopen`. I don't know why. "h" != "H" perhaps? Solve that first. Then, I think you'll  find that `_fprintf` wants the parameters in the opposite order - format string first, then *stream (in `%eax` if the `_fopen` succeeds).

Comment: Writing assembly to call a bunch of C-runtime functions is quite pointless, a C compiler already knows how to do that.  Forgetting to take care of error handling and not cleaning up the stack is the fairly inevitable outcome.

Comment: @HansPassant what a silly statement. Learning is never pointless. What is worth learning is not something you can judge or consider here; it's not part of the question and your opinion about it is really the only pointless thing I can see.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing arguments to `fprintf` reversed too. Come on, pay a little more attention, you have made this mistake once already!

That shouldn't affect return value from `fopen`, though. That part works for me. Note that some environments require 16 byte alignment of the stack pointer.

By the way, `/n` is not a line feed, in case you wanted that.

Comment: Reversing that doesn't work either. It is probably something else but I can't find out what it is.

Comment: Use `strace` if available to see what system calls are made and result they give.

Comment: I'm mainly programming on windows right now so strace is not avaiable.

Comment: Windows also has system call tracer tools such as [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

Comment: OK I found the problem it turned out there was a permission problem with writing on H sorry for anyone who tried to fix this but couldn't find anything wrong and thank you for your time.